# Python ctypes returned c_char_p is corrupted

Tags: python, c++, string, character-encoding, ctypes

I have a C++ interface that contains the following:

```
extern "C"
{
     char const* getValForEntry(Entry e)
     {
         std::string no_val = "__err::no_val";
         if (handles.find(e) != handles.end())
         {
             std::string val = handles[e]->get_value();
             return val.c_str();
         }
         else
             return no_entry.c_str();
     }
}
```

I have a python app that connects to this interface with ctypes like so:

```
self.lib.getUpdateForEntry.restype = c_char_p
val = self.lib.getUpdateForEntry(e)
```

The interface returns the string:

```
{"RVC HR1":{"Mode":1,"Seq Num":162,"Home":7,"Time":"Thu Sep 01 10:00:00 2000","Flags":0,"Data Len":1024,"Data":[26, ... an array of 1024 values ... ,239]}}
```

What the python app is seeing is:

```
p??"Mode":1,"Seq Num":162,"Home":7,"Time":"Thu Sep 01 10:00:00 2000","Flags":0,"Data Len":1024,"Data":[26, ... an array of 1024 values ... ,239]}}
```

The message is suppsosed to be a string with 2844 chars in it, but in python, the first 12 chars are always corrupted, and I see the message:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

If I adjust the message to only have a handful of values in the array (under 10) then the message is fine, but when I add more values, the first part of the message gets corrupted. Does anyone know why I am seeing this? Is there a max c_char_p length, or is it being returned as ascii and converted to unicode? Is it something else?

Comment: `std::string val` is a local variable. It will go out of scope and become invalid when the function returns. `return val.c_str();` returns a pointer to a buffer that is owned by `val` and will vanish along with the rest of `val` when the function returns. Which it does right here.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with python, and everything to do with local variables in C++ having scope limited to the block they're declared in.  Similar behavior could have been observed if the caller is C++.

Comment: @user4581301 so if this is true, why is the message correct when I only put one value in the array? Val would still go out of scope, but in python the message is exactly correct.

Comment: @Austin -- *so if this is true, why is the message correct* -- Welcome to the world of C++ and undefined behavior.  The code is not correct, regardless of what you are observing.  Change compilers, compiler settings, etc. and you may get different results (possibly crash).

Comment: Hard to say exactly why this one looks like it works. Perhaps Short String optimization  and nothing's been written over the first few bytes of what once was the string on the stack yet. Maybe the system is holding onto some dynamically allocated storage because it suspects you'll need it again shortly. Any number of possible reasons, and this is one of the big reasons why the exact behaviour is not defined.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you recognize the code is wrong, and have a different approach in returning character data.  Spending (IMO, wasting) time on trying to reason with undefined behavior is not a good use of development resources.

Comment: The *"'utf8' codec can't decode..."* message fires because some byte is not a valid uft8 one. It happens that first 127 chars (English and common to most of rest) only need a byte to represented in utf8, so they are valid. Rest of chars need more than a single byte and the first one is a special one.

Comment: Shouldn't `no_entry` be `no_val`?

Comment: The solution is to return a pointer to buffer with a wider scope. You probably don't want to have to return a raw dynamically allocated buffer that the user will have to manually release later, but it may be the best option here if you want `getValForEntry` to be a reentrant function.

Comment: @Ripi2 -- Yes, but this is a case of "garbage out" (without the "garbage in").  So the characters could be any junk.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie user4581301 that was exactly right. I changed the variable to stay in scope and it worked perfectly in python. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See PaulMcKenzie and user4581301 comments above for explaination. The local variable val was going out of scope, which led to undefined behavior.